# Interpretation of var inside JavaScript if statement

Tags: javascript

I have been taught to define variables at the top, regardless of their position in your code, as this is how JavaScript will interpret things. So, my understanding is that:

```
var foo = "Bob";

if (2 + 2 === 4) {
    var car = "Blah";
}
```

Will be interpreted like:

```
var foo = "Bob",
    car;

if (2 + 2 === 4) {
    car = "Blah";
}
```

Is my understanding correct? I've always tried to position my variable definitions at the top of the current scope, but sometimes those variables are only needed inside an `if` statement, so defining them outside seems a bit odd - is this still best practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. `var` statements are hoisted (which is why best practise is to use them at the top of the function — it avoids confusion from people assuming block scope instead of function scope)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Variable and function declarations are [hoisted](http://www.jamesallardice.com/2011/11/21/explaining-function-and-variable-hoisting-in-javascript/) to the top of the scope in which they are defined. Since JavaScript only has function scope (and not block scope), the top of the scope in your example is outside the `if` statement.

Note that since function expressions are effectively just variable declarations, the function itself is not hoisted (as assignment occurs where you intend it to). That means it's only available after the assignment...

```
sayHello(); //Uh-oh... TypeError, undefined is not a function!
var sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hi!");
};
```

... as opposed to a function declaration, which can be used before it is defined in the source:

```
sayHello(); //"Hi!"
function sayHello() {
    console.log("Hi!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is always good to define them on top of the scope (and javascript is function scoped), you could read more about this [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet)